# AudioOutputUnitStart takes time

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I'm making an iPhone game application using Core Audio, Extended Audio File Services.

It works OK, but when I first call AudioOutputUnitStart, it takes about 1-2 seconds.
After the second call, no problem.
For a game application, 1-2 seconds is very noticeable.
(I tested this on iPhone simulator, and iPhone 3GS)

Also, if I leave the game for about 10 seconds, first call of AudioOutputUnitStart after the leave also takes time.

I'm using a 5-second AAC 160kbps file to play.

Answer (score 0):

For a 5-second file, why not convert that file into a linear PCM wav or aif file? It shouldn't be that much bigger, plus you don't have to involve the AAC decoder in the process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Actually I have 60 15-second files, so it might become big if I use PCM files, but that should be one solution.

I forgot to write here, but I found a bug in my codes. I mistakenly called AudioOutputUnitStop, and it causes startup time problem.

Now I fix it, and now it takes time only once.

Again thank you for your answer.